# Is it possible to enforce the use of a using statement in C#

Tags: c#, using

Would really like to be able to decorate my class with an attribute of some sort that would enforce the use of a using statement so that the class will always be safely disposed and avoid memory leaks. Anyone know of such a technique?

Comment: What about embedding your object in a different disposable object?

Comment: Decorating your class with IDisposable is meant to be the flag to consumers of your class that they should either wrap in a Using, or call Dispose. If you enforce the "Using" technique, you're effectively saying to your good consumers "I think you're too thick to call Dispose", and limiting usage.

Comment: I also wanted to say, are you sure there aren't scenarios where someone might want to create your object in one method, and dispose of it in another? (Perhaps they're IDisposable too). You're making it impossible for someone to do this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe that a using block also ensures that Dispose gets called even if there is an exception. There's a lot of goodness to using, I can see wanting to enforce it.

Comment: @Wedge, Yes, yes it does. But if there was never a reason why you'd want to use an IDisposable outside of a Using block, I'd imagine there would be compiler warnings/errors. Hence my comment concerning being sure that you're not neglecting possible scenarios.

Comment: Well actually it was me who was too thick. I was using a 3rd party library, never noticed that 1 class out of 100's implemented IDisposable and had a memory leak in the application because of it. So wanting to avoid that mistake in my own code I looked to the community for an answer. So silly me eh!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there's one way you could sort of do it - only allow access to your object via a static method which takes a delegate. As a very much simplified example (as obviously there are many different ways of opening a file - read/write etc):

```
public static void WorkWithFile(string filename, Action<FileStream> action)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        action(stream);
    }
}
```

If the only things capable of creating an instance of your disposable object are methods within your own class, you can make sure they get used appropriately. Admittedly there's nothing to stop the delegate from taking a copy of the reference and trying to use it later, but that's not quite the same problem.

This technique severely limits what you can do with your object, of course - but in some cases it may be useful.

Comment: I felt a bit dirty doing something similar to this. *feels better now it has Skeet endorsement*

Comment: This isn't a "new" pattern by any means - not that I can remember the name right now...

Answer (score 3):

You could use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx) to enforce this rule. See the Wikipedia for a [quick overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop).

Comment: Doesn't help when people are *using* his classes - he can't tell his users to use FxCop

Comment: Make it a part of the build and they have to pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure your object is always disposed, use a finalizer in combination with IDisposable.

But before you do, read up on IDisposable and finalizers, and be conscious of the fact that you normally don't need them unless your class is doing something like managing the lifetime of an unmanaged resource.

With a finalizer your object will be reclaimed 'eventually' whether wrapped in a using or not. The using statement, which is a convenience for IDisposable, allows deterministic cleanup to take place. The only caveat is that object with finalizers are more expensive to clean up and in general stick around in memory longer while they await finalization.

ref [When do I need to implement a finalizer or IDisposable?](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2005/06/when-do-i-need-to-implemen_111967455770395396.html)
or
[technorabble: Using Dispose, Finalizers and IDisposable](http://tech.norabble.com/2008/07/using-dispose-finalizers-and.html)